# How do I remove body parts from the two-handed spear?

Tags: gorn

In GORN, I have unlocked the two-handed spear. However, I can't get very far using this weapon, because it quickly gets clogged up with heads, limbs, hearts, etc. after I have killed a few enemies. There is no obvious way to remove these. The weapon becomes unusable, and I quickly die. For one-handed weapons, this situation is easy to deal with by scraping the body parts off with the other hand/weapon. This does not work with the two-handed spear, because both hands are needed to hold it. If I let go with one hand, the weapon goes into "noodle" mode, and I can't really do anything with it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't swinging the spear a couple of times really hard throws of the body part? Just be a maniac with the spear and no problems :D

Comment: @JoeryJV At the time I asked this question, I was having trouble getting that to work. Maybe I wasn't swinging wide and fast enough. (This game quickly taught me that swinging wide and fast tends to end with a loud crash, bleeding knuckles, and the contents of my bookshelf on the floor.) Of course, now that I know more, I'd rather just bludgeon my enemy with his fallen comrade's severed head. Far more entertaining.

Comment: You should knock a guy out, rip of his arm and then beat him to death with it, its the best :D. Typing this was weird :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach that seems to work (now that I've had a couple of weeks to play the game) is to treat spear + impaled body part as a different weapon from the plain spear. It's no longer useful for stabbing, but now you can use it like a club (which you couldn't really do with the plain spear). When you whack an enemy with a severed arm (or head, or whatever) on the end of the spear, it does damage, dislodges armor, and knocks them back briefly. Then, after a few good whacks, the body part gets dislodged and things are back to normal.